# command-line jslint like program

Tags: linux, javascript, firefox, lint

I know about [jslint](https://jslint.com/), but it has a web interface. I am a [60 years old geek using Linux](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/index_en.html) since 1993 (and have developed the [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) tool, with Bismon wanting to be some successor)

For the [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) project (GPLv3+) I am coding some handwritten JavaScript using [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), such as its [webroot/jscript/Bismon-hwroot.js](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/webroot/jscript/bismon-hwroot.js) file.

Bismon (work in progress, funded by [H2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework_Programmes_for_Research_and_Technological_Development#Horizon_2020) research projects like [Chariot](https://www.chariotproject.eu/) and [Decoder](https://www.decoder-project.eu/)) is itself some specialized web server described in this [draft report](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf), using [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion) and also some domain specific language, with a [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) close to [Scheme R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/)'s one, some reflection, some metaprogramming facilities; but Bismon is also orthogonally [persistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)), with the persistent heap stored as some `git` managed textual files such as [`store1.bmon`](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/store1.bmon).

I do know that JavaScript semantics is really weird. I want a simple tool catching some (not all) basic mistakes (lack of closing parenthesis, some typos in variable names, etc...) but I need it on the command line for Linux.

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/393837/40065) summarizes well what Bismon wants to become and give both motivations and technical context that I won't repeat here.

The HTML5 code using  [webroot/jscript/Bismon-hwroot.js](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/webroot/jscript/bismon-hwroot.js) is entirely machine generated by Bismon. FWIW, [ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/) was somehow inspirational for Bismon, and I only care about recent browsers on Linux (e.g. firefox 68 on Linux)

Bismon is a low [TRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_readiness_level) research prototype.

My Linux system is a Debian/Sid

I did compile node-v13.6.0 from its [source code](https://nodejs.org/dist/v13.6.0/node-v13.6.0.tar.gz) after a `./configure --ninja  --verbose  --enable-trace-maps --enable-lto --debug --gdb` followed by the appropriate invocation of `ninja`. Then I copied the resulting `node` executable (which works when started in a terminal) into my file `$HOME/bin/node`  and `$HOME/bin/` and my `$PATH` (for `zsh`) is set to `$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin`

I then tried

```
pcbasile node-v13.6.0/out/Release 13:56 % npm install -g jslint internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976   throw err;   ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver' Require stack:
- /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:855:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:993:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:19) {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
    '/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'   ] }
```

If I `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:$HOME/bin` I am still getting a failure, but a different one:

```
     cd $HOME
     npm install -g jslint
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.17.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
/usr/local/bin/jslint -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jslint/bin/jslint.js
+ jslint@0.12.1
updated 1 package in 1.02s
```

and I am getting the same error with `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin`

On my Debian/Sid `npm` is actually `/usr/bin/npm`, a script starting with `#!/usr/bin/env node`

PS. My login shell is [zsh](https://zsh.org/).

Comment: 1. The command `npm -g update npm` should self-upgrade `npm` and this way you could get rid of the warning. --- 2: [`eslint`](https://eslint.org/) is more powerful than `jslint` . So I'd do `npm -g i eslint`, although I think `eslint` will recommend/warn you to NOT install it globally. That is indeed cleaner because every project/directory could have its own eslint. But I think you can install globally though.

Answer (score 1):

Is there something wrong with the [jslint CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jslint#use-the-command-line-client)?

**Edit:**

The installation is very simple on Debian. The following commands assuming you are using apt as a package manager and that you are logged in as root.

1. `apt install nodejs`
2. `npm install -g jslint`

Comment: How can I use that on Debian? There is no package named `jslint` ....

Comment: Ok. I just compiled from source code Node.Js13.6.0; I got a `node` executable. Do I need anything else? Take into account that I am a node.js newbie.

Comment: I don't even understand the installation procedure of `node`...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have updated my answer with Debian installation instructions. **You should uninstall the nodejs you built from source.** After installing `jslint` via npm, every user will be able to use the `jslint` command as if it was a native utility.

Comment: Why should I uninstall the nodejs I built from source? The Debian packaged one don't work

Comment: And with the last `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin` the locally installed `$HOME/bin/node` is not even visible, and `/usr/bin/npm` is a script starting with `#!/usr/bin/env node`

Comment: If you are having problems with the apt version of node, then I guess theirs no problem using the one you built from source. `npm` should still work to install it. **If you do use your build from source, you need make the binaries visible to `PATH`.**